# How can I correctly sort items from a database in "natural" order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, natural-sort

I'm trying to sort items from a database by title. Items are `iphone 5`, `iphone 6/6S`, `iphone 11`,..

and when I sort items with code

```
SELECT *
FROM ".FPD_PRODUCTS_TABLE."
ORDER BY `title` ASC
```

I'm geting the result

```
iPhone 11
iPhone 5
Iphone 6/6S
...
```

I also tried sorting by character length, but then I get an incorrect order again.

How can I get `ASC` order that would be correct:

```
iphone 5
iphone 6/6S
iphone 11
...
```

Comment: implementing good natural sort in SQL is always tricky..  Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: .. Also consider doing the sorting in PHP instead there is a natural sorting function.  -> [natsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Comment: Another way is to add another column to specify the sort order.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I’m looking now in this option to add new column for sorting.

Comment: Actually it's not sorting incorrectly at the moment. Those are strings and it is sorting them as so. For example, when sorting 11 and 5 as strings, it comes to the first character, where 1<5 (it's not 11 and 5).  One approach would be extracting number from strings and sorting by them, if the remaining part of string is equal (ORDER BY manufacturer, model). Better approach would be having a separate column for model (number part).

Answer (score 0):

Ordering in Php:

```
<?php
$rows = [
    ['model' => 'Samsung Galaxy'],
    ['model' => 'IPhone 11'],
    ['model' => 'iPhone 5'],
    ['model' => 'iphone 6/6S']
];

$key_models = array_column($rows, 'model');
natcasesort($key_models);

foreach($key_models as $k => $v)
    echo $rows[$k]['model'], "\n";
```

Output:

```
iPhone 5
iphone 6/6S
IPhone 11
Samsung Galaxy
```